# Как искать элемент по другому адресу, если первый не подошёл Selenium Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Делаю парсер на Python и пытаюсь взять элемент с помощью Selenium. Но из-за того, что сайт может загружаться то чуть дольше, то быстрее, завернул поиск элемента в следующую структуру:

```
while True:
    try:
        csmoney_skin_wear_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th[{csmoney_skin_iterator + csmoney_skin_count}]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException as e_NoSuchElementException:
        print(f'NoSuchElementException: {e_NoSuchElementException}')
```

Всё прекрасно работает, но иногда, по неизвестной мне причине, элемент не может "найтись". Проверил и оказалось что иногда тот же элемент находится по другому адресу. Брать по CSS селектору не вариант, поэтому использую xpath. Вопрос в следующем: как сделать поиск элемента сначала по одному адресу, а потом по другому, если первый не был найден. При этом сохранить структуру, потому что ставить time.sleep не вариант. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `Брать по CSS селектору не вариант` почему? html самое то парсить css-селекторами :) Кст, то, что вы намутили с циклом и `NoSuchElementException` можно сделать нативно через ожидания используя WebDriverWait

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос кусок HTML, где будет тот элемент, что нужно найти или добавьте ссылку на сайт с указанием, что пытаетесь вытащить :)

Comment: А так, вы можете сделать два раза поиск, по двум адресам. Ограничьте их по количеству попыток, между попытками ожидание, например, в `0.1`. Если при первой попытке не нашлось, то аналогичный алгоритм для поиска второго. Но возможно проблема в вашем пути, если предоставите пример данных, что нужно вытащить, то помогу сделать запрос так, чтобы он работал внезависимости от расположения элемента от корня документа, как у вас сейчас сделано

Comment: Это похоже на проблему xy. Тут `'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th`  выглядит совсем плохо. Если хоть где-то в этом пути к корню дерева (или в соседних элементах) есть вставка javascript-ом, то неудивительно, что xpath иногда "не работает". Неужели на странице есть больше одной таблицы в которой есть заголовок с полем, которое подходит под предикат `{csmoney_skin_iterator + csmoney_skin_count}`? Может есть все же способ обойтись без столь точной (и хрупкой) спецификации пути?